# How to use both hasOne and hasMany relationships on the same type?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The Map domain has a center and a list of coordinates. Both center and path have same types which is Coordinate.

```
class Map {

    Coordinate center

    List path

    static hasOne = [center: Coordinate]

    static hasMany = [path: Coordinate]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The coordinate domain is defined as

```
class Coordinate {

    static belongsTo = [map: Map]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Now i have a simple code

```
def map = new Map(center: new Coordinate())

map.addToPath(new Coordinate())

map.save()
```

This is throwing exception

```
2016-11-02 13:08:55,970 [Thread-15] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - NULL not allowed for column "MAP_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into coordinate (id, version, map_id, path_idx) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23502-164]
Exception thrown

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [exampletest.Coordinate]; SQL [insert into coordinate (id, version, map_id, path_idx) values (null, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [exampletest.Coordinate]
```

I wonder what is the reason for the error. I thought since coordinate belongs to the Map, saving map will automatically save its children which in this case is Coordinate. I appreciate any help and fix to this issue i am stuck on. Thanks!